# Generate batches of random numbers that each are zero-sum and for which mean of the absolute values is uniformly distributed over specified interval

Tags: random, statistics, voting, statistical-test

In the context of polls of voting results, I want to generate random numbers with specific properties to sample the possibilities within the margin of error of the poll.

For example, suppose I have polling results:

- Party A: 34%
- Party B: 25%
- Party C: 14%
- Party D: 27%

With a margin of error of 3.2% on the poll-results.

I want to generate batches of 4 (because in this case there are 4 parties) random numbers. Obviously because voting is a zero-sum game, the numbers in the batch need to sum up to zero.

I want each element of the batch to be smaller (in absolute value) than the given margin of error of the poll-results.

An example could be: `(-0.5, +1.2, +0.1, -0.8)`. All the elements sum up to zero and each element is in absolute value smaller than `3.2`, i.e. the given margin of error of the poll-results.

When generating a large amount of this kind of batches of random numbers, I would like these to have some specific statistic properties:

- The maximum of the absolute values of the elements should be uniformly distributed over `(0, error_of_margin)` (this is the easy part).
- The mean of the absolute values should also be uniformly distributed over `(0, error_of_margin)`.

I tried two different approaches. I will link a gist, to not fill the question with code. https://gist.github.com/thomvil/02890ea2873eed6bb155e7dc387c9564

Does anybody have some suggestions on how I could tackle this?

Comment: You are not generating true random numbers.  If a batch sums to zero, then the last number of the batch is fully determined by the values of the previous numbers in that batch and is not random at all.

Comment: @rossum this is obviously true, but a constraint of the context of the problem. It would not make sense to have voting percentages that don't add up to 100%. This is not a problem.

Comment: You could generate random vectors of the form `(x, x, -x, -x), (x, -x, x, -x)` etc, where `x` is uniform on `[-3.2, 3.2]`. I am not sure if this is possible otherwise.

Comment: Note cross-post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/529974/generate-batches-of-random-numbers-that-each-are-zero-sum-and-for-which-mean-of

Comment: `Obviously because voting is a zero-sum game, the numbers in the batch need to sum up to zero.` Huh?!? You need them to sum up to 1 (100%).

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux i want to generate a batch of "deviations" from the poll results. Like the example i gave of `(-0.5, +1.2, +0.1, -0.8)`. This adds up to zero, because if "applied" (added to) the poll-results of `(34, 25, 14, 27)` (= the polling results of the 4 parties), the resulting variation is `(33.5, 26.2, 14.1, 26.2)`. The seat allocation of this variation is than calculated.

The goal is to repeat this for many variations, to estimate the expected variations in seat allocations

Comment: @thomvil this is wrong approach. You have to sample population, you know a lot about population. You pretty much don't know anything about errors, your sampling would be G in -> G out style.